# Puppet Master attempts to resolve agent hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, puppet, puppetmaster

Running `puppet agent -t` from a non-dns resolvable client dumps out the following from a puppet master running in verbose mode:

```
Error: Could not resolve 10.110.x.xx: no name for 10.110.x.xx
```

(Where 10.110.x.xx is the ip of my puppet agent machine)

Does a puppet agent also need to be DNS resolvable?

Comment: Interesting. I have run in production for *years* without caring for this (not using verbose mode on the master). It remains unclear what this error actually entails.

Comment: I agree it is unfortunate more information is not provided.  This makes it very tough to use puppet on global clients that may not have resolvable dns.

Comment: To make this clear: To my knowledge, there is **no** disadvantage to having unresolvable agent addresses, despite the "error" message and the documentation. I will comment again if I find any evidence that there are problems after all.

Comment: Interesting - I was looking at this message as the root cause for handshake issues between my newly built puppet master and a remote agent.  If the indication is that puppet should still function id be very interested in further information.

Comment: I can now confirm that Puppet 3.7 will emit this message regardless of verbose mode. My production has been 2.x only so far, so perhaps that's why I was spared. Also, the message appears mainly when the agents hands in its CSR (message is logged multiple times) and during the first compiler run for this agent (message is logged once). For subsequent checkins, the message apparently will not appear. TL;DR it is probably safe to ignore this error. SSL handshakes and certs signing works regardless.

Comment: This definitely affects some functions of puppet 4. Half my resources didn't get applied, but some did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the nodes must be resolvable from the puppetmaster.
This is one of the prerequisites before deploying Puppet (in a master/node setup), see https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/pre_install.html#check-your-network-configuration:

> Name resolution: Every node must have a unique hostname. Forward and
>   reverse DNS must both be configured correctly. (Instructions for
>   configuring DNS are beyond the scope of this guide. If your site lacks
>   DNS, you must write an /etc/hosts file on each node.)